# Aren't [wireless-access-point] and [access-point] the same?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

Is there a non wireless access point? If yes, why does the [access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access-point) tag has the following description:

> Wireless access point (WAP) is a device that allows wireless devices to connect to a wired network

Currently there are 422 questions tagged as [wireless-access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-access-point) and 54 as [access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access-point). Shouldn't one tag be merged to the other and be a tag synonyme for it?

Comment: By the way: `[tag:access-point]` will create a tag link.

Comment: I *think* so...unless we're reminiscing about the access points [between ISPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_access_point) of long ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Merge [access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access-point) with [wireless-access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-access-point) and make the former a synonym of the latter.

For Super User's target audience, the terms **access point** and **wireless access point** are synonymous. Strictly speaking, the definition of *access point* need not be restricted to wireless technology, but such questions are highly likely to involve enterprise-like environments and therefore IMO be more appropriate for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

It's worth noting that *all* of the currently 54 questions tagged [access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access-point) deal with wireless access points.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes and No.

A wireless router for instance is a wireless access point and it is also a wired access point, in most cases. You can plug devices into the ethernet ports on the router and also connect to it through wireless. So, could the two tags be merged? In this case, I would think they should be.

On the flip side, think of a switch, or a hub in a network, they do not have wireless capability but, they are an access point (through wires) into the network. In this instance, the two tags should not be merged, maybe clarified.

In closure, change [access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access-point) to [wired-access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wired-access-point) OR get rid of [wireless-access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-access-point) and leave all access points regardless of how they are accessed as [access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access-point).

Comment: Considering that very few of the [tag:access-point] questions are specifically about _wired_ access points, I don't think having separate tags makes sense. I'm in favor of the latter option (everything folded into [tag:access-point]).

Comment: I agree, the two really should just become [tag:access-point] because our world is becoming more and more dependent on wireless infrastructures. Most people don't even know what a switch closet looks like anymore...

Comment: Wired ap questions are corporate related and might be better served on serverfault. Where does wired ethernet infrastructure still get used these days?

Comment: @Reaces wired infrastructures get used all over the place (mostly in corporate environments like you said). You just don't see them anymore, they are hidden in closets or in the attic or basement. Personally I still run a wired network because it's faster and ultimately more reliable than wireless for gaming and/or downloading things. I have wireless for my other devices (phone, tablet, etc). I think wired infrastructures will go the way of the Dodo eventually but, for now, they still have their uses.

Comment: @reeves True they're still there behind the scenes... But usually even then handled by professionals not the end (super)user.

Comment: @Reaces - I think we're agreeing that [tag:wired-access-point] and [tag:wireless-access-point] should be merged with [tag:access-point] and be left at that... Haha

Comment: @Reeves I'd like to disagree with the degree of use of wired infrastructure.  My Wii, tablet (android), and iPhone (wife's device) are wireless, but they are a minority on the network.  As to an Internet connection that is supplied as ethernet, instead of as cable, DSL, other and converted to ethernet, I'd say that ethernet internet is still rare aside from businesses, and probably still rare for businesses.  I have no intention whatsoever of wireless-ing my devices.  Clueless humans may choose to go wireless for everything, but the keyword is clueless.  Many devices should never be wireless.